# jQuery detect element in viewport - calc causing issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect when an element is completely out of the viewport, I have this so far...

```js
/* Pause video if out of viewport */
jQuery(function($) {
    
//this function runs every time you are scrolling

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top_of_element = $(".element").offset().top;
    var bottom_of_element = $(".element").offset().top + $(".element").outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (bottom_of_screen < bottom_of_element)){
        // The element is visible, do something
  console.log('visible');
    }
    else {
  console.log('not visible');
        // The element is not visible, do something else
    }
});


})
```

```css
html, body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.header {
  background:blue;
  position:fixed;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:9999;
}

.element {
  height:calc(100vh - 100px);
  background:wheat;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div class="header">
    This is a fixed header
  </div>

  Scroll Down
  
  <div class="element">
    This is a test element
  </div>

</div>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed mauris sed elit porttitor ultricies. Donec ut dolor vestibulum massa viverra fermentum. Maecenas dignissim risus turpis, et euismod urna tincidunt sed. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. In ut erat felis. Suspendisse in magna et odio tempus mattis eget auctor sem. Nullam vitae euismod ex, sed auctor nisi. Aenean placerat enim et arcu pulvinar rutrum. Mauris ligula risus, mollis at libero vel, lobortis semper magna. Integer at felis lacus. Quisque massa quam, cursus vel mauris convallis, pellentesque molestie ipsum. Donec efficitur orci et dui fermentum, id porttitor nisi scelerisque. Suspendisse elementum finibus luctus. Suspendisse varius sem et lorem sodales ultrices.
</p>
<p>
Nulla ex enim, convallis sit amet rutrum egestas, blandit non arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris eget auctor est, et congue velit. Nulla pellentesque, tellus vitae ultrices rutrum, purus sem fermentum neque, eget eleifend sem sapien eget nunc. Praesent nec nunc quis nunc dignissim efficitur. Sed erat augue, volutpat sed mattis id, consequat sit amet metus. Morbi dignissim justo lorem. Ut ultrices mattis tincidunt. Quisque posuere, leo eget congue venenatis, urna velit accumsan justo, consequat vulputate ligula odio placerat enim. Duis eu venenatis lorem. Sed volutpat, libero sed fringilla viverra, augue ante sagittis massa, nec tristique nibh mi eu justo. Aenean viverra mauris nunc, vel porttitor diam dictum ac.
</p>
<p>
Fusce commodo tempor sem, non tempus metus lobortis at. Ut hendrerit placerat nisi nec venenatis. Quisque congue accumsan nulla, sit amet suscipit neque eleifend sit amet. Donec lacinia velit in odio ornare, at congue ante auctor. Suspendisse lacinia magna purus, a tempor erat lacinia nec. Etiam sed orci varius, euismod ante efficitur, lobortis neque. Phasellus varius libero gravida erat placerat, ornare euismod lectus dignissim. Suspendisse at lacus ut massa aliquam eleifend.
</p>
<p>
Proin semper orci et augue eleifend tempus eu in urna. Vivamus elementum massa sed ligula fringilla, nec blandit ante efficitur. Etiam varius maximus sem, at laoreet sem sodales nec. Nunc quis dolor in orci ultrices congue a ac turpis. Praesent pharetra quam felis, molestie luctus sem maximus sed. Phasellus consequat felis sed tortor sagittis mollis. Ut at interdum lacus. Quisque ac turpis id arcu pulvinar volutpat. Vestibulum finibus mi euismod arcu ultrices, ac efficitur nibh tempus. Nulla in magna porta, bibendum libero ut, molestie est.
</p>
<p>
Curabitur tristique rutrum erat, non tristique quam feugiat at. Nunc id urna eget eros tincidunt dapibus. Aliquam ut ornare sem, at mattis risus. Aliquam blandit bibendum aliquet. Nunc rhoncus euismod libero. Phasellus congue sit amet sem non ornare. Morbi justo ligula, auctor et turpis vitae, euismod vestibulum nunc.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed mauris sed elit porttitor ultricies. Donec ut dolor vestibulum massa viverra fermentum. Maecenas dignissim risus turpis, et euismod urna tincidunt sed. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi. In ut erat felis. Suspendisse in magna et odio tempus mattis eget auctor sem. Nullam vitae euismod ex, sed auctor nisi. Aenean placerat enim et arcu pulvinar rutrum. Mauris ligula risus, mollis at libero vel, lobortis semper magna. Integer at felis lacus. Quisque massa quam, cursus vel mauris convallis, pellentesque molestie ipsum. Donec efficitur orci et dui fermentum, id porttitor nisi scelerisque. Suspendisse elementum finibus luctus. Suspendisse varius sem et lorem sodales ultrices.
</p>
<p>
Nulla ex enim, convallis sit amet rutrum egestas, blandit non arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris eget auctor est, et congue velit. Nulla pellentesque, tellus vitae ultrices rutrum, purus sem fermentum neque, eget eleifend sem sapien eget nunc. Praesent nec nunc quis nunc dignissim efficitur. Sed erat augue, volutpat sed mattis id, consequat sit amet metus. Morbi dignissim justo lorem. Ut ultrices mattis tincidunt. Quisque posuere, leo eget congue venenatis, urna velit accumsan justo, consequat vulputate ligula odio placerat enim. Duis eu venenatis lorem. Sed volutpat, libero sed fringilla viverra, augue ante sagittis massa, nec tristique nibh mi eu justo. Aenean viverra mauris nunc, vel porttitor diam dictum ac.
</p>
<p>
Fusce commodo tempor sem, non tempus metus lobortis at. Ut hendrerit placerat nisi nec venenatis. Quisque congue accumsan nulla, sit amet suscipit neque eleifend sit amet. Donec lacinia velit in odio ornare, at congue ante auctor. Suspendisse lacinia magna purus, a tempor erat lacinia nec. Etiam sed orci varius, euismod ante efficitur, lobortis neque. Phasellus varius libero gravida erat placerat, ornare euismod lectus dignissim. Suspendisse at lacus ut massa aliquam eleifend.
</p>
<p>
Proin semper orci et augue eleifend tempus eu in urna. Vivamus elementum massa sed ligula fringilla, nec blandit ante efficitur. Etiam varius maximus sem, at laoreet sem sodales nec. Nunc quis dolor in orci ultrices congue a ac turpis. Praesent pharetra quam felis, molestie luctus sem maximus sed. Phasellus consequat felis sed tortor sagittis mollis. Ut at interdum lacus. Quisque ac turpis id arcu pulvinar volutpat. Vestibulum finibus mi euismod arcu ultrices, ac efficitur nibh tempus. Nulla in magna porta, bibendum libero ut, molestie est.
</p>
<p>
Curabitur tristique rutrum erat, non tristique quam feugiat at. Nunc id urna eget eros tincidunt dapibus. Aliquam ut ornare sem, at mattis risus. Aliquam blandit bibendum aliquet. Nunc rhoncus euismod libero. Phasellus congue sit amet sem non ornare. Morbi justo ligula, auctor et turpis vitae, euismod vestibulum nunc.
</p>
```

It is not working for unless I remove the calc from the .element height.

How can I modify this so that it takes my sticky header into account?

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* Pause video if out of viewport */
jQuery(function($) {
  //this function runs every time you are scrolling
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var top_of_element = $(".element").offset().top;
    var bottom_of_element = top_of_element + $(".element").outerHeight();
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrolled + $('.header').height() < bottom_of_element && scrolled + $(window).height() > top_of_element) {
      console.log('visible');
    } else {
      console.log('not visible');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.element {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    This is a fixed header
  </div>

  Scroll Down

</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed mauris sed elit porttitor ultricies. Donec ut dolor vestibulum massa viverra fermentum. Maecenas dignissim risus turpis, et euismod urna tincidunt sed. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi.
  In ut erat felis. Suspendisse in magna et odio tempus mattis eget auctor sem. Nullam vitae euismod ex, sed auctor nisi. Aenean placerat enim et arcu pulvinar rutrum. Mauris ligula risus, mollis at libero vel, lobortis semper magna. Integer at felis
  lacus. Quisque massa quam, cursus vel mauris convallis, pellentesque molestie ipsum. Donec efficitur orci et dui fermentum, id porttitor nisi scelerisque. Suspendisse elementum finibus luctus. Suspendisse varius sem et lorem sodales ultrices.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed mauris sed elit porttitor ultricies. Donec ut dolor vestibulum massa viverra fermentum. Maecenas dignissim risus turpis, et euismod urna tincidunt sed. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi.
  In ut erat felis. Suspendisse in magna et odio tempus mattis eget auctor sem. Nullam vitae euismod ex, sed auctor nisi. Aenean placerat enim et arcu pulvinar rutrum. Mauris ligula risus, mollis at libero vel, lobortis semper magna. Integer at felis
  lacus. Quisque massa quam, cursus vel mauris convallis, pellentesque molestie ipsum. Donec efficitur orci et dui fermentum, id porttitor nisi scelerisque. Suspendisse elementum finibus luctus. Suspendisse varius sem et lorem sodales ultrices.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed mauris sed elit porttitor ultricies. Donec ut dolor vestibulum massa viverra fermentum. Maecenas dignissim risus turpis, et euismod urna tincidunt sed. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi.
  In ut erat felis. Suspendisse in magna et odio tempus mattis eget auctor sem. Nullam vitae euismod ex, sed auctor nisi. Aenean placerat enim et arcu pulvinar rutrum. Mauris ligula risus, mollis at libero vel, lobortis semper magna. Integer at felis
  lacus. Quisque massa quam, cursus vel mauris convallis, pellentesque molestie ipsum. Donec efficitur orci et dui fermentum, id porttitor nisi scelerisque. Suspendisse elementum finibus luctus. Suspendisse varius sem et lorem sodales ultrices.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed mauris sed elit porttitor ultricies. Donec ut dolor vestibulum massa viverra fermentum. Maecenas dignissim risus turpis, et euismod urna tincidunt sed. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi.
  In ut erat felis. Suspendisse in magna et odio tempus mattis eget auctor sem. Nullam vitae euismod ex, sed auctor nisi. Aenean placerat enim et arcu pulvinar rutrum. Mauris ligula risus, mollis at libero vel, lobortis semper magna. Integer at felis
  lacus. Quisque massa quam, cursus vel mauris convallis, pellentesque molestie ipsum. Donec efficitur orci et dui fermentum, id porttitor nisi scelerisque. Suspendisse elementum finibus luctus. Suspendisse varius sem et lorem sodales ultrices.
</p>
<p>
  Nulla ex enim, convallis sit amet rutrum egestas, blandit non arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris eget auctor est, et congue velit. Nulla pellentesque, tellus vitae ultrices rutrum, purus sem fermentum neque, eget eleifend sem sapien eget nunc. Praesent
  nec nunc quis nunc dignissim efficitur. Sed erat augue, volutpat sed mattis id, consequat sit amet metus. Morbi dignissim justo lorem. Ut ultrices mattis tincidunt. Quisque posuere, leo eget congue venenatis, urna velit accumsan justo, consequat vulputate
  ligula odio placerat enim. Duis eu venenatis lorem. Sed volutpat, libero sed fringilla viverra, augue ante sagittis massa, nec tristique nibh mi eu justo. Aenean viverra mauris nunc, vel porttitor diam dictum ac.
</p>

  <div class="element">
    This is a test element
  </div>
<p>
  Fusce commodo tempor sem, non tempus metus lobortis at. Ut hendrerit placerat nisi nec venenatis. Quisque congue accumsan nulla, sit amet suscipit neque eleifend sit amet. Donec lacinia velit in odio ornare, at congue ante auctor. Suspendisse lacinia
  magna purus, a tempor erat lacinia nec. Etiam sed orci varius, euismod ante efficitur, lobortis neque. Phasellus varius libero gravida erat placerat, ornare euismod lectus dignissim. Suspendisse at lacus ut massa aliquam eleifend.
</p>
<p>
  Proin semper orci et augue eleifend tempus eu in urna. Vivamus elementum massa sed ligula fringilla, nec blandit ante efficitur. Etiam varius maximus sem, at laoreet sem sodales nec. Nunc quis dolor in orci ultrices congue a ac turpis. Praesent pharetra
  quam felis, molestie luctus sem maximus sed. Phasellus consequat felis sed tortor sagittis mollis. Ut at interdum lacus. Quisque ac turpis id arcu pulvinar volutpat. Vestibulum finibus mi euismod arcu ultrices, ac efficitur nibh tempus. Nulla in magna
  porta, bibendum libero ut, molestie est.
</p>
<p>
  Curabitur tristique rutrum erat, non tristique quam feugiat at. Nunc id urna eget eros tincidunt dapibus. Aliquam ut ornare sem, at mattis risus. Aliquam blandit bibendum aliquet. Nunc rhoncus euismod libero. Phasellus congue sit amet sem non ornare.
  Morbi justo ligula, auctor et turpis vitae, euismod vestibulum nunc.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed mauris sed elit porttitor ultricies. Donec ut dolor vestibulum massa viverra fermentum. Maecenas dignissim risus turpis, et euismod urna tincidunt sed. Nulla facilisi. Nulla facilisi.
  In ut erat felis. Suspendisse in magna et odio tempus mattis eget auctor sem. Nullam vitae euismod ex, sed auctor nisi. Aenean placerat enim et arcu pulvinar rutrum. Mauris ligula risus, mollis at libero vel, lobortis semper magna. Integer at felis
  lacus. Quisque massa quam, cursus vel mauris convallis, pellentesque molestie ipsum. Donec efficitur orci et dui fermentum, id porttitor nisi scelerisque. Suspendisse elementum finibus luctus. Suspendisse varius sem et lorem sodales ultrices.
</p>
<p>
  Nulla ex enim, convallis sit amet rutrum egestas, blandit non arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris eget auctor est, et congue velit. Nulla pellentesque, tellus vitae ultrices rutrum, purus sem fermentum neque, eget eleifend sem sapien eget nunc. Praesent
  nec nunc quis nunc dignissim efficitur. Sed erat augue, volutpat sed mattis id, consequat sit amet metus. Morbi dignissim justo lorem. Ut ultrices mattis tincidunt. Quisque posuere, leo eget congue venenatis, urna velit accumsan justo, consequat vulputate
  ligula odio placerat enim. Duis eu venenatis lorem. Sed volutpat, libero sed fringilla viverra, augue ante sagittis massa, nec tristique nibh mi eu justo. Aenean viverra mauris nunc, vel porttitor diam dictum ac.
</p>
<p>
  Fusce commodo tempor sem, non tempus metus lobortis at. Ut hendrerit placerat nisi nec venenatis. Quisque congue accumsan nulla, sit amet suscipit neque eleifend sit amet. Donec lacinia velit in odio ornare, at congue ante auctor. Suspendisse lacinia
  magna purus, a tempor erat lacinia nec. Etiam sed orci varius, euismod ante efficitur, lobortis neque. Phasellus varius libero gravida erat placerat, ornare euismod lectus dignissim. Suspendisse at lacus ut massa aliquam eleifend.
</p>
<p>
  Proin semper orci et augue eleifend tempus eu in urna. Vivamus elementum massa sed ligula fringilla, nec blandit ante efficitur. Etiam varius maximus sem, at laoreet sem sodales nec. Nunc quis dolor in orci ultrices congue a ac turpis. Praesent pharetra
  quam felis, molestie luctus sem maximus sed. Phasellus consequat felis sed tortor sagittis mollis. Ut at interdum lacus. Quisque ac turpis id arcu pulvinar volutpat. Vestibulum finibus mi euismod arcu ultrices, ac efficitur nibh tempus. Nulla in magna
  porta, bibendum libero ut, molestie est.
</p>
<p>
  Curabitur tristique rutrum erat, non tristique quam feugiat at. Nunc id urna eget eros tincidunt dapibus. Aliquam ut ornare sem, at mattis risus. Aliquam blandit bibendum aliquet. Nunc rhoncus euismod libero. Phasellus congue sit amet sem non ornare.
  Morbi justo ligula, auctor et turpis vitae, euismod vestibulum nunc.
</p>
```

Comment: That works well for the top but not when it exits the viewport at the bottom